# how to index nested JSON containing sparsely populated geo_point data?

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I'm running Elasticsearch v6.7.2 and want to index JSON that looks like this:

```
{
    "src": {
        "ip": "10.0.1.32"
    },
    "dst": {
        "ip": "74.6.168.73",
        "location": {
            "lat": 37.751,
            "lon": -97.822
        }
    },
    "in": 197.0,
    "out": 76.0,
    "timestamp": 1.557746197E12
}
```

As you can see, the JSON is nested. The `lat`/`lon` values are attributes of the `location` which, in turn, belongs to a `src` (source) or `dst` (destination).

If geolocation data doesn't exist for a source or destination IP address, the `location` attribute is missing from the JSON. For example, the source address in the example above is a private IP, which does not have an associated entry in the IP geolocation service.

I'm trying to figure out how to create a mapping in Elastic so the timestamp field (Unix millis), and location(s) are stored/indexed as the correct types so they can be searched. The location(s) should be stored as the `geo_point` type.

A couple of things are confusing me:

1. The JSON is nested, so the mapping definition needs to account for
   this.
2. The location is sparsely populated. Hopefully, it'll handle
   JSON with missing attributes.

The "automagic" indexer, visible from Kibana, doesn't appear to handle recognise that `{"location": {"lat": ..., "lon": ...}}` is a `geo_point`:

Does anyone know how I could create a mapping for this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the mapping I used:

```
PUT src_dst_enriched
{
    "mappings": {
        "src_dst_enriched": {
            "properties": {
                "src": {
                    "properties": {
                        "location": {
                            "type": "geo_point"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "dst": {
                    "properties": {
                        "location": {
                            "type": "geo_point"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "timestamp": {"type": "date"}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can now see IP addresses on a map in Kibana:

[image: map]